# Charging a capacitor. Calculations and PSpice simulation don't match

Tags: capacitor, matlab, pspice

I started using PSpice only yesterday and I have a problem with a really simple circuit.

Vs = 2 V

R1 = 1 kΩ

C1 = 50 nF

The switch closes at t = 0 (it's not really needed).

[image: Charging a 0.05uF capacitor]

After running a Time Domain analysis and tracing the voltage across the capacitor, I saw that it takes around **~250ms** to raise the Vc to Vs.

[image: Time Domain Analysis Trace]

This seemed like too much time, so I decided to double check in MatLab by graphing a function of voltage across a charging capacitor:

\$\ Vc(t) = Vs \cdot (1- e^{-{{t}\over{RC}}}) \$

where

\$RC = 1kΩ \cdot 50 nF = 0.00005s \$

\$Vs = 2 V\$

I can't post the screenshot of the result, because I don't have enough reputation for another link. But it's easy to check that the Vc reaches 2 V shortly after t = **0.25ms**.

Why do I get different results for the same circuit in PSpice?

Comment: Hmm, something somewhere is out by a factor of 1000 in your simulation. It should indeed reach \$V_s\$ at around \$5\tau = 5RC = 250\mu s\$. I would try redoing the simulation to make sure there is nothing cached and that it is actually simulating the circuit you are intending it to simulate.

Comment: What is the on and off resistance of the switch? Are you sure it actually closed?

Comment: @Mario Yes, it was probably because of the switch. I removed it altogether and now everything seems right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch is the main problem. I'm not 100% sure here but I see at least 2 problems with the switch:
1. The closing time is defined as 1s, not 0s as you expected (So actually the switch opened during your whole simulation)
2. The default resistance value of the switch is 1 MOhm. So the switch itself is similar to a big resistor and your time constant in this case is:
tau = R_sw * C = 1M * 50n = 50 ms
That's why it took about 250ms for Vc to reach Vs value

Comment: Yeah, the switch was causing the problem, as Mario suggested in comments. I removed it altogether and everything worked fine. BTW, welcome to EE Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thank Max. By the way, I thought you want to use that sw_tclose component to model the switch? Removing it will be helpful in this case only. You'll be in the same trouble if the closing time of the switch is at 2 seconds for example :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future. Haven't simulated any circuits for almost a year now.

Answer (score 0):

First I will ask a question and then I will answer your question.
I drew an RC circuit in x and got an output from the result. But I don't see the charge of the capacitor in the output. I don't know where the problem is. The simulator only shows me the final result and the infinite V, which is a straight line.
If I want to say based on your circuit, I see the same 2 volts in the output, and the simulator does not show the charge graph of the capacitor.

And now your answer

The RC equation that you mentioned is related to the time constant of charging the capacitor in the RC circuit. The number 250 milliseconds is actually the time it takes to fully charge the capacitor. But that 50 milliseconds is actually the time it takes until the charge of the capacitor reaches 63%. If you look at the same circuit that you simulated, you will see that the voltage of the capacitor has reached 1.26 V (63% of the source voltage) at t=50s. In addition, we can consider the capacitor charged in 250 seconds (almost full charge in each circuit after 5 time constants)